# Strapi V4: how to enrich ctx.query.populate?

Tags: middleware, strapi, endpoint

Let's say I call my endpoint with those parameters :

> GET
> /api/articles?populate[0]=seoData&populate[1](https://strapi.io/blog/route-based-middleware-to-handle-default-population-query-logic)=seoData.sharedImage&populate[2]=seoData.sharedImage.media

I want my middleware to alter what's populated.  There is an example in the official documentation here : [Route-Based Middleware to Handle Default Population Query Logic](https://strapi.io/blog/route-based-middleware-to-handle-default-population-query-logic).

But what I understand is that, in this example, they show how to *override*  `ctx.query.populate`, they don't show how to append more data to it.

Since the `populate` parameter from the endpoint is an array, and that the `ctx.query.populate` parameter from their example is an object, how can I combine them ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> how can I combine them?

With JavaScript!

You will have to decide if you middleware should create an array or an object in the end. If you receive the populate params in the query in the wrong format, you'd need to convert it.

Let's take the example:

```js
GET /api/articles
  ?populate[0]=seoData
  &populate[1]=seoData.sharedImage
  &populate[2]=seoData.sharedImage.media
```

In your middleware, you will receive the parsed populate param and then you can convert it to your target format and merge it with whatever you want to add. Here is some code to get your started.

```js
// your-middleware.js

let existingPopulate = ctx.query.populate;
```

While `ctx.query` will always be defined as an object, `populate` can be either an Array, an Object or undefined. So you'd need to check for those cases.

```js
// your-middleware.js

const defaultPopulate = {
  attribute: true,
};

let mergedPopulate;

if (Array.isArray(existingPopulate)) {
  // existingPopulate will be
  // [
  //   'seoData',
  //   'seoData.sharedImage',
  //   'seoData.sharedImage.media',
  // ]

  // convert Array to Object here
}

if (existingPopulate instanceof Object) {
  mergedPopulate = {
    ...existingPopulate,
    ...defaultPopulate,
  }; // or use a deep merge algorithm
} else {
  mergedPopulate = defaultPopulate;
}

ctx.populate = mergedPopulate;

// continue
```

**IF** you have that kind of power over your clients, you could make you life easier, though, if you decide not to support array notation at all and send your existing populate params as a stringified object in the first place:

```
// on your client

const query = qs.stringify({
  populate: {
    seoData: {
      populate: {
        sharedImage: {
          populate: {
            media: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

=> GET /api/articles
  ?populate[seoData][populate][sharedImage][populate][media]=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What would be better is a method for strapi to uniformize ctx.populate and retrieve it in a single format.

Comment: You can always create a [github issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues) or a [feature request](https://feedback.strapi.io/) for that.